# dojo.destroy() make node empty, not delete it

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dojo

i've got a table, where dynamically adding and deleting rows. When i need to remove some  element, it's not deleting, it's only make it emty.
here's remove function:

```
        function remove() {
            dojo.forEach(
                dojo.query(".selectedMail"),
                function(selectTag) {
                     dojo.destroy(selectTag);
                }
              );
        }
```

here's selecting function:

```
        var myBehavior = {
            ".row": {
                //onclick: dojo.addClass(evt.target, "buttonDown")
                onmousedown: function(evt) {
                    if(dojo.hasClass(evt.target, "selectedMail"))
                        dojo.removeClass(evt.target, "selectedMail");
                    else
                        dojo.addClass(evt.target, "selectedMail");
                }
            }
        };
```

here's table:

```
    <table>
        <tbody id="tbody123">
            <tr class="row">
                <td >simplesimplesimplesimplesimple</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row">
                <td>simplesimplesimplesimplesimple</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row">
                <td>simplesimple</td>
            </tr>
            <tr class="row">
                <td>simple</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

after remove() executing there remaining: 
here's full source:
http://pastebin.com/0YN5TKvG

Answer (score 1):

`dojo.destroy` is working just fine, you need to examine your DOM more carefully. You are adding the class of "selectedMail" to the `td` element, `dojo.destroy` is completely removing that element and (of course) leaving the parent `tr` element alone.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
dojo.destroy(selectTag);
```

You can use dojo.empty

```
dojo.empty(selectTag);
```